# Javascript: Repeatedly Auto Refresh Webpage with an ON-OFF Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I would like to use Javascript to auto-refresh my webpage while users can choose to turn on/turn off the auto-refresh function with two different buttons (Please be aware that the buttons are using `<label>` and `<input>` tag). I have tried my best to write the code but I still do not know how to link up these two codes so that it can function correctly.

Also, if user choose the buttons of auto-refresh ON, I want to keep auto refresh continuously after its first load instead of just auto refreshing only once.

Would you please help me to correct my codes, please? Thank you.

The code for ON and OFF buttons (two individual buttons):

```
<div class="page-header-actions" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" value="autorefreshoff" checked />
    <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i> Auto Refresh OFF
  </label>
  <label onClick="startrefreshon" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="autorefreshon" />
    <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i> Auto Refresh ON
  </label>
</div>
```

The code for auto-refresh function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this unfortunately. You may be able to STOP the refresh but you won't be able to turn it back on again, not with out refreshing the page.

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers Oh, how about if I want to turn on auto refresh in default once it load the page, it can turn off the refresh function by clicking the auto refresh off button? Is it possible?

Comment: @FrederickM.Rogers Let's me explain more. I would like to enable the auto refresh ON function in default once it load the page (i.e. it will repeatedly auto refresh the page in every 1 minute), the user can choose to turn off the auto refresh function by clicking Turn OFF button (i.e. the page will not auto refresh any more)? Is it possible and how should I write the code?

Comment: Seams like @vsr figured it out. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few things you need to do:

1. Both the `input type="radio"` should have same `name`.
2. Give the 'auto refresh on' button an ID, so that you can reference it easily in JavaScript code (say `auto-refresh-checkbox`).
3. Write a reload function that checks if the checkbox is `checked`

code:

```
function reloadPage(){
  var refreshEnabled = document.getElementById('auto-refresh-checkbox');
  if(refreshEnabled.checked) {
    window.location.reload(1);
  }
}
```

4. Then call this function via `setInterval`

`setInterval(reloadPage, 5000);`

---

PS: The checked "auto refresh" radio will lose it's value on page reload, so you might have to save the value using localStorage or something else.

Comment: Great! Your code works fine. How about if I want to enable the auto refresh ON function in default once it load the page (i.e. it will repeatedly auto refresh the page in every 1 minute), the user can choose to turn off the auto refresh function by clicking Turn OFF button (i.e. the page will not auto refresh any more)? Is it possible and how should I write the code?

Comment: To make it default ON, move the `checked`  attribute from OFF radio button to the ON radio button in your html.

Comment: Yes, it works! :) Now it can keep refreshing once it loads. So, how can I stop auto refreshing the page by clicking the OFF button?

Comment: If you've followed the first point in the answer, OFF button should be working.

Comment: @Dennis, if this solution works you should make mark it as "answer".